# Screenshots don't get automatically copied. Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, screenshot, copy, paste

When I take a screenshot it just gets saved in my pictures folder but doesn't get copied automatically anymore. Before I was able to paste my screenshots right after taking them but it suddenly stopped working for some reason. Have had a bunch of small issues like this with Ubuntu since the 20.04 Update..

Comment: Assuming you have Gnome desktop, pressing `ctrl + print screen` will take the shot and copy it to the clipboard. As far as I can tell this was always the default behavior (could be wrong don't use Gnome). You can change this by using the keyboard shortcuts app from settings.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal run

```
gnome-screenshot -c
```

and add -d   for a delay to test anything else which you can switch to after running it

and then if that works better, make a custom ubuntu keyboard shortcut for it